# Put multiple lines of a file as a single element of array

Tags: perl

Text file contains

```
pChainCtrl 
pNewRoute 
pCurrRoute 

pChainCtrl 
pNewRoute 
pCurrRoute 
pMod

pChainCtrl 
pNewRoute
```

Is it possible to put the set of elements into an array like

```
array a[0] = pChainCtrl 
             pNewRoute 
             pCurrRoute 

a[1] =      pChainCtrl 
            pNewRoute 
            pCurrRoute 
            pMod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open my $fh, "data.txt" or die;
my $file = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh;

my @a = split /\n{2,}/, $file;
```

Comment: If you set `$/` to an empty string, rather than `undef` then this all becomes much simpler - `my @a = do { local $/ = ''; <$fh> };`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the input record separator `$/` to `""` (i.e., `local $/ = "";`) to split the input on empty lines (see perldoc perlvar for details).